# Draw the corresponding AC circuit

Tags: transistors, ac, dc

I have the following transistor, whose I have calculated the parameters that were not given.

Now, I want to draw the corresponding AC circuit.
Can someone help me with this or give me any source where I can learn more about it.
[image]

Does C2 need to be included when drawing the AC circuit ?

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid. Your U1 and U2 arrows should be pointing up as the voltage measurements will be referenced to ground.

Comment: @Transistor, I tried to save it but it says I need a membership, I tried the same with sharing the link, same also

Comment: "Save to Workbench" requires an account. "Save and Insert" doesn't.

Comment: Replace the Cs with shorts and the Ls with open.  The "AC equivalent" generally refers to an approximation assuming the frequency is high enough to make the impedance of C and the admittance of L negligible.  Include C2, but L1 makes C3 unnecessary.

Comment: @Cristobol Polychronopolis, I want to draw the ac circuit because i want to find the transfer function U2/U1

Comment: @be1995 Okay, but the answer is the same.  Remove all the inductors and short all the caps.